# Need a better approach for calculating rate when selecting a max value inside a group by (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to get a daily difference for a statistic in my table so I can plot the data. I have a facebook_stats table that is taking 'snapshots' at 5 minute intervals.

I'm trying to grab the last entry for each day and calculate the difference between consecutive days, e.g., on feb 4 i have 20 entries and on feb 5 i have 50.

Get the last of feb 4, the last of feb 5, calculate the difference in page_likes. Perhaps this would be easier if i start throwing a flag for last entry on my table? Perhaps I'm doing way more than I need to with this MYSQL? I don't know enough about MYSQL, so I'm asking here to see if there is a better way to accomplish this.

The code below gets the expected results, but it is quite expensive and takes ~2-3 seconds on my dev.

```
   SELECT t1.timestamp, (t2.page_likes - t1.page_likes) as rate
    FROM facebook_stats t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `timestamp`, max(id) id, page_likes, handshake_id 
                 FROM facebook_stats
             GROUP BY DATE(`timestamp`) , handshake_id ) t2
    ON t1.handshake_id = t2.handshake_id
    AND DATE(t1.timestamp) + 1 = DATE(t2.timestamp)
    WHERE t1.id IN (
        SELECT t1.id
        FROM facebook_stats t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `timestamp`, max(id) id, page_likes, handshake_id 
                        FROM facebook_stats
        GROUP BY DATE(`timestamp`) , handshake_id ) t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
        GROUP BY DATE(t1.timestamp), t1.handshake_id
    )
    GROUP BY DATE(t1.timestamp), t1.handshake_id;
```

I've thought about running the inner query and just updating the records just after midnight with a flag "last_entry" or the actual rate itself or something like that. I've also thought about using PHP to further filter the results (without the where, the query is fast enough).

I would like to know which solution is the most appropriate based on convention and efficiency. I'm leaning toward making a 'rate' column and having most be null, and the last ones of the day contain the rate. Then I can just grab all the columns with a non-null value.
Suggestions?
Thanks

Here is the table structure if people are curious:

facebook_stats

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| timestamp     | timestamp        | YES  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| handshake_id  | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| page_likes    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| status_likes  | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| status_shares | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

---

## Edit

I may not have been clear with what I'm trying to gather.

The page_likes data is the total number of likes for the page at the time I ran the process (every 5 min). It's not an additive process; it's a snapshot of what is currently on the Facebook page.

That being said, I care more about the rate of change per day, i.e., today's ending page_likes - yesterday's ending page_likes for every day in the table.

The end goal is to create a graph that shows the rate of change per day for the facebook page likes. An example dataset would probably look like this:

```
array(
    "2014-02-5" => 20, 
    "2014-02-6" => 5, 
    "2014-02-7" => -1,
    "2014-02-7" => 2,
     ...
);
```

So on Feb 5, the page had 500 likes at the end of the day (last entry). On the 4th it had 480 at the end of the day. 500 - 480 = 20.

Hopefully that clarifies what I'm trying to gather a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Doing aggregates on the fly such as this have been brought up many times out here and everyone's scenario appears to be somewhat different and thus the question asked again for their particular needs.  The answer I would offer is to denormalize in these situations.

Since it appears you want the totals from the end of one day to the next, I would offer something along the lines of adding a column "likes_yesterday" (int) to the table that tracks total likes/dislikes, etc such that can represent

Then, based on triggers for insert, update, delete, do something along the lines of...

```
if the date of timestamp before the update is the day prior to the new update
   update the Likes_YesterDay = page_likes,
              Page_Likes = 1,
              timestamp with current time
else
   update the Page_Likes = Page_Likes +1,
              timestamp with current time
```

for the given ID/Handshake.  Yes, the actual trigger sample above is inaccurate per lack of context of the values and what you are tracking.

You could also have another column for whatever purpose such as "FirstLikeForDay" also a timestamp column, so that would get set the same time you moved the current likes to the yesterday likes, and could stamp that too when the date rolls-over to a new day.

Comment: I like the suggestion to denormalize the data in these types of situations. However, I know practically nothing about triggers. I'll definitely investigate this option and come back here and accept the answer if it works. (I updated the question, so hopefully the context is a bit more clear) Cheers.